# Expression<TDelegate>.Compile() on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, expression

As stated in the doc, this method is not supported on WP8. But I tried it anyway and it works in the emulator. I dont have a test device right now, has anybody tried it already?

Comment: As I can see in the MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362.aspx, Version Information section):
.NET for Windows Store apps
Supported in: Windows 8

Comment: I was referring to Windows Phone 8

Comment: I'm sorry, I was inattentive.

Comment: Tried it in Lumia 520 and it works. Will try it on more complex scenarios...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Expression.Compile` was not supported in WP7, since it depended on `Reflection.Emit` which was not included in WP7. WP8 however now supports `Expression.Compile`. The [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) IoC framework for instance, makes use of this internally and supports WP8 and Windows Store Apps.